# ReactJS component with supporting disabled javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, templates, reactjs

I have an application where I want to use ReactJS component (let's say for tree menu). And I need to support browsers with disabled javascript.

**Scenario 1 - Enabled javascript, using Reactjs**:
Tree menu can be expanded and collapsed down to unlimited levels without reloading the page. You can expand arbitrary amount of nodes.

**Scenario 2 - disabled javascript, using generated HTML:**
You can expand only one path in tree menu. After click to an menu element, page is re-rendered (and URL is changed to reflect the page state). So you go click after click and reload after reload. This is just fallback solution.

How do you cope with such a situation so you don't have to maintain two different templates (**HTML**/**ReactJS**)?

Isn't there any possible solution to bind **ReactJS** to existing (already rendered) **HTML**?

Comment: Check out react-router-mega-demo. [Demo](http://react-router-mega-demo.herokuapp.com/) [Src](https://github.com/rackt/react-router-mega-demo). The key is server-side rendering, and some careful design of how the react components in use.

Comment: Well I suppose the key is server-side rendering, but I don't really see how this would help me.